# Fully-qualified class name of links while parsing Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, annotation-processing

In [a Java annotation processor](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-tools/blob/1c3a5a2f9dbe087d48e1c7404e3e9a6a5eaf66e7/log4j-docgen/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/docgen/processor/DescriptorGenerator.java), I use `DocTrees#getDocCommentTree(Element)` to obtain a `DocCommentTree`, which I walk over with a visitor. [Visitor's `visitLink(LinkTree,C)` method](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-tools/blob/1c3a5a2f9dbe087d48e1c7404e3e9a6a5eaf66e7/log4j-docgen/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/docgen/processor/AbstractAsciiDocTreeVisitor.java#L227) is invoked for found `{@link` tokens. For a `{@link Foo}`, `LinkTree#getReference().getSignature()` returns `Foo`, though it doesn't give you the fully-qualified class name. That is, is it `java.lang.Foo`? Is it `Foo` in the same package? Is it some `Foo` class imported? How can I get the fully qualified name of the reference while parsing links in Javadoc?

Comment: It means the current package.

Comment: Did you mean to link to [Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) and [DocTreeVisitor.visitLink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/source/doctree/DocTreeVisitor.html#visitLink(com.sun.source.doctree.LinkTree,P))?  Log4J source code doesn’t seem like a useful reference.

Comment: @user207421, no, it doesn't necessary mean the current package. If you import `com.foo.Bar`, you can link to it using `{@link Bar}`.

Comment: @VGR, it is not an arbitrary piece of code I referenced, it is *the* Log4j Tools code base I am working on, hence the link. (See my name in the commits there.)

Comment: I see.  I believe the answer is that `import` statements which don’t end with an asterisk take precedence over everything else.  If no `import` statement specifies the class name, the doclet will look in the same package as the referencing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While parsing Javadoc in an annotation processor, we can first create an `ImportTree` and use it to determine the FQCN of a `ReferenceTree` returned by `LinkTree#getReference()`, that is, the FQCN in `{@link signature label}`. I have already implemented this for `log4j-docgen` in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-tools/commit/47806471625ffee75061baf3753ff5a378010cd8). The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
public class ExampleProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private DocTrees docTrees;

    private Trees trees;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(final ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        docTrees = DocTrees.instance(processingEnv);
        trees = Trees.instance(processingEnv);
    }

    private void scanDocTree(Element element) {
        Map<String, String> imports = collectElementImports(element);
        ExampleContext context = new ExampleContext(imports);
        DocCommentTree tree = docTrees.getDocCommentTree(element);
        ExampleDocTreeVisitor visitor = new ExampleDocTreeVisitor();
        tree.accept(visitor, context);
    }

    private static final class ExampleDocTreeVisitor<Void, ExampleContext>
            extends SimpleDocTreeVisitor<Void, ExampleContext> {

        @Override
        public Void visitLink(LinkTree linkTree, final ExampleContext context) {
            String signature = linkTree.getReference().getSignature();
            String fqcn = context.imports.get(signature);
            // ...
            return super.visitLink(node, data);
        }

    }

    private Map<String, String> collectElementImports(Element element) {
        ImportCollectingTreeScanner scanner = new ImportCollectingTreeScanner();
        TreePath treePath = trees.getPath(element);
        scanner.scan(treePath.getCompilationUnit(), null);
        return scanner.imports;
    }

    private static final class ImportCollectingScanner
            extends TreeScanner<Object, Trees> {

        private final Map<String, String> imports = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        public Object visitImport(ImportTree importTree, Trees trees) {
            Tree qualifiedIdentifier = importTree.getQualifiedIdentifier();
            String qualifiedClassName = qualifiedIdentifier.toString();
            String simpleClassName = qualifiedClassName.substring(qualifiedClassName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            imports.put(simpleClassName, qualifiedClassName);
            return super.visitImport(importTree, trees);
        }

    }

}
```

#### Credits

- @piotr-p-karwasz for the `ImportTree` hint
- [Andi's blog](http://sahits.ch/blog/blog/2016/08/06/documentation-generation-with-the-compiler-api/) on how to extract `ImportTree` in an annotation processor

Comment: `DocTrees` extends `Trees`, so you can use a single field in your example.